# what is the git equivalent of SVN UPDATE?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

With SVN you can delete a local file (put it in the trash can) and restore it by running svn update after the delete. The SVN client will simply pull a fresh copy of the file (and nothing else gets touched in the directory).

I haven't been able to figure it out with GIT.

I'm using Tortoise Git on Windows and a 'pull' or a 'fetch' doesn't restore the file. I don't want to have to check out the entire repository (clone) again...

Comment: If you know the file is named `restore/me`, use `git checkout -- restore/me`.  If you don't know the name of the file, use `git status` to find the name of the file.

Comment: @torek : thanks. it works from a cmd prompt, but not from Tortoise Git. And it's annoying that I have to type the name of the file. In SVN, if any files are missing (because I deleted them), then an SVN UPDATE will restore all the files...What is the equivalent action I have to take in Tortoise GIT?

Comment: I don't use Tortoise Git so I don't know.  Git has `reset --hard` but that's quite different: it means "make the index and working directory both match the given commit, and move the branch to that point."

Answer (score 1):

You could do "check for modifications" and then you ll see a list of deleted files. Right click any file and chose revert

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to restore all deleted files by using a combination of commands. Obviously this only works for files you deleted but whose deletion you didn't commit yet.

The command chain in question could look like this:

```
git checkout -- $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D)
```

As torek already explained in the comments `git checkout` is the command that restores the file, the interesting part happens at the `git diff` command.
The `--name-only` option tells `diff` to only print the filenames of the changed files, while the `--diff-filter=D` takes care that everything but **deleted** files is getting ignored.

For easier usage you can create an alias which will also allow you to use the command in CMD. Creating an alias could look like this:

```
git config --global alias.restore '!git checkout -- $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D)'
```

*You will have to use double quotation marks (`"`) on CMD.*

You will then be able to use the command easily with `git restore`.

For further information you can take a look at the [`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff), [`checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) and [`config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) documentation.